# Android how to close db when query execute

Tags: android

i have a websearch and db search ,this can be done at the same time , in db search am using db cursor for setting the result ,also for making search faster am open the db in OnCreate() and close it in onPause ,both the websearch and dbsearch running in separate async task ,when websearch result comes first am starting new activity,if db query is still executing am not able to close the db, how can close the db in this situation ,please help me

i get the following exeception

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Unable to close due to unfinalised statements

Answer (score 0):

You may write DB operation in separate thread and start the result activity once thread execution completes.

Comment: is there  anyway to close the db when query execute

Comment: Will you please explain what you want to do actually?

Comment: when my websearch result comes first i finish the current activity and start new one ,in onPause am close the db ,but if the query in execution am not able to close the db. Both the web search and db search are running in separate async task

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force close the database.

You need to close all the cursors for the different queries you have running on that database.

Since your queries are running in separate `ASyncTask`, you need to keep track of those and [`cancel`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) them (you can close the cursors in the [`onCancelled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onCancelled%28Result%29) callback function)

Comment: i have use single async task, and if new db search start i cancel the current search and restart new one, but i can't block the query in execution

Comment: that's ok, you can wait until it's done... and if there are several queries, check for isCancelled in between

Answer (score 0):

i have opend the db in my application class and solved my problem